# Filtering Datatable -Missing operand after @

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable, dataview

I'm using the following code to filter a datatable to show tuples that contain my email address.But i keep getting `Missing Operand after @` Error.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("select * from mytable",connection);
    // SqlDataReader dataReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(mycommand.ExecuteReader());
    string value = "me@live.com";
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.RowFilter = "email = "+value;

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
    //  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: No need to go thru those gyrations with the DataView.  You can apply a filter to the DataSource or even a persistent DT directly.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.defaultview?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Just use `where` clause in the `SqlCommand` with specified value - no need to filter the `DataTable` after it has already populated.

Comment: Also try enclose the value with single quotes - because `@` is a special character to identify query parameters, and it should be escaped as string.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto The single quote solved the issue

Comment: As @Developer asked in his answer, do you really need to fetch *all* the rows from the database? If not, if would be much better do let the database do the filtering instead of your application.

Comment: @Andrew I'm just figuring out how to filter DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
string value = "me@live.com";
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.RowFilter = "email = "+value;
```

What you are doing is:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.RowFilter = "email = me@live.com";
```

Therefore you are missing the apostrophes to enclose the literal string. You should use this instead:

```
string value = "'me@live.com'";
```

So the resulting filter is:

```
dv.RowFilter = "email = 'me@live.com'";
```

As you are probably getting the email from somewhere else (instead of hardcoded in your file), if you are using C# 6.0 or greater, you could do this instead:

```
string value = "me@live.com";
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.RowFilter = $"email = '{value}'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
  connection.Open();
  var query = "select * from mytable WHERE email = 'me@live.com'";
  SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand(query,connection);
  // SqlDataReader dataReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Load(mycommand.ExecuteReader());
  DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

  dataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
  // dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you filtering after Fetching whole data from the database? Just filter it in query itself :

> select * from mytable where email = 'me@live.com'

Answer (score -1):

Try this and let me know if it works

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
  connection.Open();
  SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("select * from mytable",connection);
  // SqlDataReader dataReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Load(mycommand.ExecuteReader());
  string value = "me@live.com";
  DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
  dv.RowFilter = "email LIKE %'" + value + "'%";

  dataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
  //  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: Missing operator exception.

Comment: dv.RowFilter = String.Format("email= '{0}'", value);